# Ошибка javax.persistence.RollbackException при добавлении записи в таблицу

Tags: java, postgresql, rest, jpa, ejb

При попытке выполнения Post метода addUser возникает ошибка:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /rest-tt-1.0-SNAPSHOT/api/users/add: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.RollbackException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: {
    "date_time": "null",
    "sender": "null",
    "senderId": "0",
    "id": "null",
    "view": "false",
    "message": "null",
    "taskId": "null",
    "deleted": "false"
}.
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:82)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:346)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:456)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.RollbackException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: {
    "date_time": "null",
    "sender": "null",
    "senderId": "0",
    "id": "null",
    "view": "false",
    "message": "null",
    "taskId": "null",
    "deleted": "false"
}.
```

Насколько я знаю, получение транзакции при использовании @ejb необязательно.
Если убрать получение транзакции в методе, то ошибки не возникает, но запись не появляется в таблице.
У меня чего-то не хватает в persistence.xml?

Имеется сущность:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)

@NamedQuery(name = "UserEntity.findAll",
query = "SELECT u FROM UserEntity u")

@NamedQuery(name = "UserEntity.findById",
query = "SELECT user FROM UserEntity user "
        + "WHERE user.id = :id")
public class UserEntity implements User{

    @Version
    private long version;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;
    private String surname;
    private String name;
    private String middlename;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String password;
    private User.Role role;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = NoticeEntity.class) //
    @JoinColumn(name = "notice_id")
    private Notice notice;
//Геттеры, сеттеры
```

Рест класс:

```
@Path(value="/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UsersRESTService {

    @EJB
    private UserService user;

    /**
     * Просмотр информации о пользователе
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/get/{id}")
    public UserResource getUser(@PathParam("id") String id) {

        Date date_time_notification = new Date();
        NoticeResource noticeResource = new NoticeResource(date_time_notification, "Sender", 1, 1516, true, "message",
                111, false);

        NoticeEntity notice = new NoticeEntity(noticeResource);

        UserResource userResource = new UserResource(id, "Иванов", "Иван", "Иванович",
                "Ivan@ivan.com", "11-22-33", "1234567890", User.Role.CONTROLLER, notice.getId());
        return userResource;
    }

    /**
     * Создание нового пользователя
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    public Response addUser(UserResource userResource) { // without id
        UserResource newUserResource = user.addUser(userResource); // with id

        if (userResource != null) { // with id
            String result = "New user with id = " + newUserResource.getId() + " was added : " + newUserResource.toString();
            return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
        }
        else {
            return Response.status(404).entity("Incorrect input").build();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Обновление данных пользователя
     */
    @PUT
    @Path("/edit")
    public Response editUser(UserResource userResource) {
        UserResource newUserResource = user.updateUser(userResource);
        String result = "Task with id = " + newUserResource.getId() + " was updated : " + newUserResource.toString();

        return newUserResource != null ? Response.status(200).entity(result).build() : Response.status(404).entity("Incorrect input").build();
    }

    /**
     * Удаление пользователя
     */
    @DELETE
    @Path("/delete/{id}")
    public Response deleteUser (@PathParam("id") String id) {

        return user.deleteUser(id) ? Response.status(200).build() : Response.status(404).entity("Incorrect input").build();
    }

    /**
     * todo
     * Авторизация нового пользователя
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/auth")
    public Response authUser(UserResource userResource) {
        if (userResource != null) {
            String result = "User authorization : " + userResource.toString();
            return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
        }
        else {
            return Response.status(404).entity("Incorrect input").build();
        }
    }

}
```

Бин:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class UserService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "tasktimePersist")
    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Добавление юзера
     */
    @Transactional
    public UserResource addUser (UserResource userResource) {

        EntityTransaction tr = em.getTransaction();

        UserEntity user = new UserEntity(userResource);
        UserResource newUserResource;

        if (this.validationUser(user)) {
            tr.begin();
            em.persist(user);
            tr.commit();
            newUserResource = new UserResource(user);
            return newUserResource;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Удаление юзера
     */
    @Transactional
    public boolean deleteUser (String id) {
        UserEntity user = this.getUserById(id);

        em.lock(user, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
        if (user != null) {
            em.merge(user);
            em.remove(user);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Обновление юзера
     */
    @Transactional
    public UserResource updateUser (UserResource userResource) {
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity(userResource);
        UserResource newUserResource;

        em.lock(user, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
        if (this.validationUser(user)) {
            em.merge(user);
            newUserResource = new UserResource(user);
            return newUserResource;
        }
        else {
            return null; // false
        }
    }

    /**
     * Получение юзера по id
     */
    @Transactional
    public UserEntity getUserById (String id) {
        TypedQuery<UserEntity> query =
                em.createNamedQuery("UserEntity.findById", UserEntity.class)
                        .setParameter("id", id).setLockMode(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
        UserEntity userEntity = query.getSingleResult();
        return userEntity;
    }

    /**
     * Получение всех юзеров
     */
    @Transactional
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {

        TypedQuery<UserEntity> query =
                em.createNamedQuery("UserEntity.findAll", UserEntity.class).setLockMode(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
        List<UserEntity> results = query.getResultList();

        return results.stream()
                .map(userEntity -> (User)userEntity)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public boolean validationUser (UserEntity userEntity) {
        if (userEntity != null && userEntity.getMiddlename() != null && userEntity.getSurname() != null
                && userEntity.getName() != null && userEntity.getRole() != null) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

persistence.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="tasktimePersist" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/TaskTime</jta-data-source>
        <class>ru.pt.tasktime.core.persist.entities.UserEntity</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation-action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation-target" value="database-and-scripts"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="здесь url"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1111"/>

            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="ru.pt.tasktime.core.persist.IDSequenceGenerator"/>

            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="createDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="dropDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation-mode" value="ddl_database_generation" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="create"/>-->
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="./create.sql"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="./drop.sql"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема найдена.
Таблицы бд пустые. Поле данное сущности связано с другой сущностью, соответственно возникает ошибка заполнения для этого поля.